# Python Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have a function `findMaxEval` which I invoke in a following way:

`eMax0,var0=findMaxEval(np.diag(eVal0),q,bWidth=.01)`

where `np.diag(eVal0)` is an ndarray of shape `(1000,)`, `q` is a number (10).

`findMaxEval` has the following definition:

```
def findMaxEval(eVal,q,bWidth):
    out=minimize(lambda *x:errPDFs(*x),.5,args= (eVal,q,bWidth),bounds=((1E-5,1-1E-5),))
    if out['success']:var=out['x'][0]
    else:var=1
    eMax=var*(1+(1./q)**.5)**2
    return eMax,var
```

This funtion tries to minimize `errPDFs` which is defined as follows:

```
def errPDFs(var,eVal,q,bWidth,pts=1000):
    pdf0=mpPDF(var,q,pts)
    pdf1=fitKDE(eVal,bWidth,x=pdf0.index.values)
    sse=np.sum((pdf1-pdf0)**2)
    return sse
```

`var` is a number which I pass in the `findMaxEval` function in `minimize`, initial value is 0.5.

Further, `mpPDF` and `fitKDE` are defined:

```
def mpPDF(var,q,pts):
    eMin,eMax=var*(1-(1./q)**.5)**2,var*(1+(1./q)**.5)**2
    eVal=np.linspace(eMin,eMax,pts)
    pdf=q/(2*np.pi*var*eVal)*((eMax-eVal)*(eVal-eMin))**.5
    pdf=pd.Series(pdf,index=eVal)
    return pdf
```

```
def fitKDE(obs,bWidth=.25,kernel='gaussian',x=None):
    if len(obs.shape)==1:obs=obs.reshape(-1,1)
    kde=KernelDensity(kernel=kernel,bandwidth=bWidth).fit(obs)
    if x is None:x=np.unique(obs).reshape(-1,1)
    if len(x.shape)==1:x=x.reshape(-1,1)
    logProb=kde.score_samples(x) # log(density)
    pdf=pd.Series(np.exp(logProb),index=x.flatten())
    return pdf
```

When I invoke `findMaxEval` (first line in the description), I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-abd7cf64e843> in <module>
----> 1 eMax0,var0=findMaxEval(np.diag(eVal0),q,bWidth=.01)
      2 nFacts0=eVal0.shape[0]-np.diag(eVal0)[::-1].searchsorted(eMax0)

<ipython-input-24-f44a1e9d84b1> in findMaxEval(eVal, q, bWidth)
      1 def findMaxEval(eVal,q,bWidth):
      2     # Find max random eVal by fitting Marcenko’s dist
----> 3     out=minimize(lambda *x:errPDFs(*x),.5,args= (eVal,q,bWidth),bounds=((1E-5,1-1E-5),))
      4     if out['success']:var=out['x'][0]
      5     else:var=1

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    598         return _minimize_neldermead(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
    599     elif meth == 'powell':
--> 600         return _minimize_powell(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
    601     elif meth == 'cg':
    602         return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, maxls, **unknown_options)
    333 
    334     while 1:
--> 335         # x, f, g, wa, iwa, task, csave, lsave, isave, dsave = \
    336         _lbfgsb.setulb(m, x, low_bnd, upper_bnd, nbd, f, g, factr,
    337                        pgtol, wa, iwa, task, iprint, csave, lsave,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in func_and_grad(x)
    278     # unbounded variables must use None, not +-inf, for optimizer to work properly
    279     bounds = [(None if l == -np.inf else l, None if u == np.inf else u) for l, u in bounds]
--> 280 
    281     if disp is not None:
    282         if disp == 0:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    324 
    325     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
--> 326         ncalls[0] += 1
    327         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    328 

<ipython-input-24-f44a1e9d84b1> in <lambda>(*x)
      1 def findMaxEval(eVal,q,bWidth):
      2     # Find max random eVal by fitting Marcenko’s dist
----> 3     out=minimize(lambda *x:errPDFs(*x),.5,args= (eVal,q,bWidth),bounds=((1E-5,1-1E-5),))
      4     if out['success']:var=out['x'][0]
      5     else:var=1

<ipython-input-23-24070a331535> in errPDFs(var, eVal, q, bWidth, pts)
      1 def errPDFs(var,eVal,q,bWidth,pts=1000):
      2     # Fit error
----> 3     pdf0=mpPDF(var,q,pts) # theoretical pdf
      4     pdf1=fitKDE(eVal,bWidth,x=pdf0.index.values) # empirical pdf
      5     sse=np.sum((pdf1-pdf0)**2)

<ipython-input-17-565d70018af2> in mpPDF(var, q, pts)
     10     eVal=np.linspace(eMin,eMax,pts)
     11     pdf=q/(2*np.pi*var*eVal)*((eMax-eVal)*(eVal-eMin))**.5
---> 12     pdf=pd.Series(pdf,index=eVal)
     13     return pdf

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    312 
    313     def _init_dict(self, data, index=None, dtype=None):
--> 314         """
    315         Derive the "_data" and "index" attributes of a new Series from a
    316         dictionary input.

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

I don't understand what should be 1-Dimensional. `np.diag(eVal0)` is of shape `(1000,)`.

I looked at all the other similar questions, but none seems to help me solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is unrelated to bounds.

For some reason minimize() calls the custom function errPDFs() with the argument to be optimized - minimize() calls this for x0 - which is an array. So if you redefine the function errPDFs() to extract the first element of an array:

```
def errPDFs(var, eVal, q, bWidth, pts=1000):
    print("var:"+var)
    pdf0 = mpPDF(var[0], q, pts) #theoretical pdf
    pdf1 = fitKDE(eVal, bWidth, x=pdf0.index.values) #empirical pdf
    sse = np.sum((pdf1-pdf0)**2)
    print("sse:"+str(sse))
    return sse
```

It should work.

Sample output:

```
>>> out = minimize(lambda *x: errPDFs(*x), .5, args=(eVal, q, bWidth),bounds= 
 ((1E-5, 1-1E-5),))
 var:[0.5]
 sse:743.6200749295413
 var:[0.50000001]
 sse:743.6199819531047
 var:[0.99999]
 sse:289.1462047531385
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Indeed if you print out ‘var’ as the minimization is happening you see that it’s an array, and I haven’t been accessing it in the right way. You pointed out correctly on the implementation of mlfinlab.
I’m also implementing code snippets from "Machine Learning for Asset Managers”, and that’s where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Updated 6/29 ... I got it to run this way, which is strange because it is the same thing, must be a bug in the library or casting explicitly like this gets it into the precise format desired:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

def findMaxEval(eVal, q, bWidth):
    bnds = ((float(1e5/10000000000), float(0.99999*-1)),)

    print(bnds)
    out = minimize(lambda *x: errPDFs(*x), .5, args=(eVal, q, bWidth), bounds=bnds)
    if out['success']: var = out['x'][0]
    else: var = 1
    eMax = var*(1+(1./q)**.5)**2
    return eMax, var

def errPDFs(var, eVal, q, bWidth, pts = 1000):
    pdf0 = mpPDF(var, q, pts)
    pdf1 = fitKDE(eVal, bWidth, x=pdf0.index.values)
    sse=np.sum((pdf1-pdf0)**2)
    return sse

def mpPDF(var, q, pts):
    eMin, eMax=var*(1-(1./q)**.5)**2,var*(1+(1./q)**.5)**2
    eVal = np.linspace(eMin, eMax, pts)
    pdf = q/(2*np.pi*var*eVal)*((eMax-eVal)*(eVal-eMin))**.5
    pdf = pd.Series(pdf, index=eVal)
    return pdf

def fitKDE(obs, bWidth = .25, kernel='gaussian', x=None):
    if len(obs.shape) == 1: obs = obs.reshape(-1, 1)
    kde=KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bWidth).fit(obs)
    if x is None: x = np.unique(obs).reshape(-1, 1)
    if len(x.shape) == 1: x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
    logProb = kde.score_samples(x)
    pdf=pd.Series(np.exp(logProb), index=x.flatten())
    return pdf

eMax0, var0 = findMaxEval((1000,), 10, bWidth=.01)

print(eMax0)
print(var0)
```

Here is the updated output on Macbook in PyCharm Community, Python version 3.8.1:

[image]

Comment: This code works now but it doesn't provide appropriate result.

Comment: I’ll take a look and reply a little later this evening

Comment: I accidentally added a comment without finishing it. Here it is:
Your code works but it doesn't provide appropriate result.
I see that for the right bound you've set 1-1e5 (-99999), which is less than left bound 1e-5 (0.00001). In this case the code works, but the function is not optimized, i.e. the value for 'var' is 1, which is set in case optimization is 'false'.
I don't understand why it won't work when I set bounds for (0.00001, 0.99999).

Comment: I see... I am working presently but will look at this this evening and get back. Interesting, we’ll figure it out no worries

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts as now I am scratching my head too yet I believe this is what was desired and it produces same results - JP

Comment: Thanks. Got stuck on this too. Are you also working on: "Machine Learning for Asset Managers (Elements in Quantitative Finance) " ? Ive started on implementing code snippets and excersises here: https://github.com/emoen/Machine-Learning-for-Asset-Managers

Comment: Most welcome. Nope, I’m just a developer and have been studying applied machine learning in python for about four years now by reading a lot of books, taking a lot of MOOC courses and playing with a lot of code. The thing is I’m lucky becauseI get to spend a lot of time on this because I do this sort of thing in my daily job about half the time

Comment: Oops Endre, forgot to say, I’ll check out your repo. Thanks guys, l8r —- JeanPierre

Comment: @JeanpierreFisher - I found an error in this code. When you run the code above you always gets variance of 1. And when you run minimize() you get an error - which you dont get if you run findMaxEval():
>>> minimize(lambda *x: errPDFs(*x), .5, args=(eVal, q, bWidth), bounds=bnds)
      fun: array(0.)
 hess_inv: <1x1 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([0.])
  message: 'ERROR: NO FEASIBLE SOLUTION'
     nfev: 0
      nit: 0
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([0.5])

Comment: There is also an implementation of code snippets and more on mlfinlab on github. There they unpack the array: https://github.com/hudson-and-thames/mlfinlab/blob/master/mlfinlab/portfolio_optimization/risk_estimators.py#L449

Comment: The Question asked pertains to the Python Exception "Data Must Be One Dimensional". I have provided a proper solution that has been up-voted twice, and I demonstrated casting to overcome strict numeric input formatting expectations of the Python library or libraries (numeric, scientific, modeling) in question.

Now, we're getting into the specifics of the model and going beyone the scope of the Question asked in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Jeanpierre. What @EndreMoen showed in his answer is what solves the problem for me. I posted the question with this title because this is what I was getting as an error and couldn’t move forward. Turned out to have nothing to do with defining bounds as we thought.
Do you both think I should edit the question? I feel like there’s good flow in the comments already for future readers to understand.